# How to rotate a large commutative diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams

To produce my commutative diagrams I use the `amscd` and `xy-Pic` packages.

I have a very wide commutative diagram that I wish to rotate counterclockwise by 90 degrees and place it by itself on a page, so that it will fit that way vertically on one page. How do I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Can't you just rotate the elements of the diagram by 90 itself? It will remain a commutative diagram....

Comment: `\rotatebox{90}` ?

Comment: If you want the caption to rotate with it, see the rotfloat package.